# porting multi-module Android Intellij Project to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

I have an android project in Intellij IDEA using the classical format that I want to port to Android Studio using gradle.

My project consists of multiple modules with dependencies between them:

```
/root
  module1/
  module2/
  appModule/
```

`module1` and `module2` are library modules. `appModule` is the actual android app and is currently using both `module1` and `module2` as dependencies.

How do I achieve this with gradle?

I currently have a gradle file for each module but im having trouble int the `appModule/build.gradle` making it refer to the other modules. Im guessing I need a `build.gradle` in the root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root `build.gradle` file is optional.

what you need is having a `settings.gradle` file in your root project and specify all module and then in your appModule' s `build.gradle` file, add:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':module1')
  // others modules goes here...
}
```

Comment: I'm facing another issue right now, I've asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465727/reference-resources-in-androidmanifest-xml-from-project-dependency). I would appreciate it if you can take a look.